# Autofill textbox (php)

Tags: php, html, css, forms, registration

I want to create a reservation hotel for my project.

The client can search for a room on website, and I right side of the room box has a "Book this room" button.

What I want is , when the client click on that button, it goes on another page with a formular. And the number of the room (or room_id) the client selected to be on that formular, without typing that manually.

The formular should be :

Room number : 2 (this field I want to be automatically filled in when the client press the button)
Firstname : ---

LastName : ----

etc.

My code is in php. I'm new on php, and I don't have any idea how should I do this. 
Thank you.

Comment: Use session()... or cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could create a function to get rooms by room number like:

```
function find_room_by_number($room_number) {
global $connection; //your mysqli connection

$safe_room = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $room_number);

$query = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_number = '{$safe_room}' LIMIT 1";
$room_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if($room = mysqli_fetch_assoc($room_set)) {
    return $room;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

}

and then on that click button you make sure you are sending a room number like:

```
<a href="room.php?number=<?php echo urlencode($rooms['number']); ?>">Room Name</a>
```

and last on the room.php you can do this to get the room number:

```
$room = find_room_by_number($_GET['number']);
```

now you can just echo the room number anywhere you like:

```
<?php echo $room['number']; ?>
```